# How to set max width of block element inside table to 100% of viewable area?

Tags: html, css

To understand what I mean, please see this snippet:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tbody><tr><td>
        <div style="width: 100%">
            <img src="myimage.png" />
        </div>
    </td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

If `myimage.png` is smaller than the browser window, the `div` is renderd to fit the window size. So far so good. But if the `img` is larger, everything exceeds the viewable area.

Is there a way to let set the `img` width to something like "100% of the image, but not larger than 100% of the viewable area"?

UPDATE:
`max-width: 100%` for the image seems not to do the job inside tables:
http://jsfiddle.net/h58Ra/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max-width` is exactly what you should use: http://jsfiddle.net/h58Ra/ (on the `img`). The `div` should never exceed the size with or without `width: 100%`.

If you remove the `max-width: 100%` in the fiddle you'll notice how the `div` still doesn't get larger, even though the `img` does.

Apparently the `div` was inside a `table` which for some reason made it fail. We reached a solution together: (from the comments) "If I set style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%"for the table, everything works fine".

Comment: Ok, it is because everything is nested inside a table, please see my updates. Thank you!

Comment: You didn't actually update the fiddle (or at least forgot to change the link), but I did now and it still works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/h58Ra/1/. On a side note, what is the table doing there anyway? Seems like it serves no purpose (and is completely un-semantic) at least in the HTML posted in your question.

Comment: Thank you for updating the fiddle. And yes, shame on me because I'm using tables for layout, but it is because of JSF which renders layout grids as tables.
I found the solution, thanks to your help, while looking for the table/max-width problem. If I set `style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%"`for the table, everything works fine. Maybe you want to update your answer like this. Here's your checkmark anyway (in advance).